# Input button click not firing on jquery and asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html, input, click

well I've never used jQuery on ASP.NET only PHP and now I have this problem because I have an input type button and with jQuery I have a click function but it's not firing. If anyone knows why and how this could be fixed. This is my code:

```
    <asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js">

        $(document).ready(function(e) {
            var usuario = $("#tbUsername").text();
            var password = $("#tbPassword").text();

            var jsonInfo = "usuario:" + usuario + "," + "password:" + password;

            $("#btLogin").click(function () {

                alert('Click');

            });

            function _throwError(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("Request: " + XMLHttpRequest.toString() + "Status " + textStatus);
            }

            function _onSuccess(data, Status, jqXHR) {
                if (data == 'authenticated') {
                    alert('User authenticated');
                }
                else {
                    alert('User and password do not match');
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">

    </style>
    </asp:Content>
```

And this is my ASP.NET code, it's all on the client side:

```
    <asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <h2>
        Please login to continue:
    </h2>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Username: </label></td><td><input id='tbUsername'></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Password: </label></td><td><input id='tbPassword'></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="button" value="Login" id="btLogin"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <div id="resultado"></div>
    <p>

    </p>
</asp:Content>
```

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js" >
</script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#btLogin").click(function () {

                alert('Click');

            });
        });

    </script>
```

Comment: Thank you that was it, I forgot that important part. Awesome @serbasi

Comment: Im not sure, but it did run in normal HTML, I tried it on Sublime as a normal HTML document and it did work.